# GitLab analyze job queue waiting time

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is there a built-in way to get an overview how long jobs, by tag, spend in queue, to check if the runners are over- or undercommited? I checked the Admin Area, but did not find anything, have I overlooked something?

If not, are there any existing solutions you are aware of? I tried searching, but my keywords are too broad and as such the results are as broad, and found nothing yet.

*Edit*: I see the job REST API can return all runner's jobs and has `created_at`, `started_at` and `finished_at`, maybe I'll have to analyze that.

Answer (score 1):

[GitLab 15.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/11/22/gitlab-15-6-released/#admin-area-runners-job-queued-and-duration-times) (November 2022) starts implementing your request:

> ### Admin Area Runners - job queued and duration times
>
> When GitLab administrators get reports from their development team that a CI job is either waiting for a runner to become available or is slower than expected, one of the first areas they investigate is runner availability and queue times for CI jobs.
>
> While there are various methods to retrieve this data from GitLab, those options could be more efficient.
> They should provide what users need - a view that makes it more evident if there is a bottleneck on a specific runner.
>
> The first iteration of solving this problem is now available in the GitLab UI.
> GitLab administrators can now use the runner details view in **Admin Area > Runners** to view the queue time for CI job and job execution duration metrics.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_6/admin-runners-job-statistics.png -- Admin Area Runners - job queued and duration times]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/#administering-runners) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/335102).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the [runners API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html) to list the status of all your active runners. So, at any given moment in time, you can assess how many active jobs you have running by [listing each runners 'running' jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html#list-runners-jobs) (use `?status=running` filter).

So, from the above, you should be able to arrive at the number of currently running jobs. You can compare that against your maximum capacity of jobs (the sum of the configured jobs limits for all your runners).

However, if you are at full capacity, this won't tell you *how much* over capacity you are or how big the job backlog is. For that, you can look at the pending queue under `/admin/jobs`. I'm not sure if there's an official API endpoint to list all the pending jobs, however.

---

Another way to do this is through GitLab's prometheus metrics. Go to the `/-/metrics` endpoint for your GitLab server (the full URL can be found at `/admin/health_check`). These are the prometheus metrics exposed by GitLab for monitoring. In these metrics, there is a metrics called `job_queue_duration_` that you can use to query metrics on the queue duration for jobs. That is -- how long jobs are queued before they begin running. You can even delimit project by project or whether the runners are shared or not.

To get an average of this time per minute, I've used the following prometheus query:

```
sum(rate(job_queue_duration_seconds_sum{jobs_running_for_project=~".*",shard="default",shared_runner="true"}[1m]))
```

Although the feature is currently deprecated, you could even create this metric in the builtin metrics monitoring feature, using `localhost:9000` (the gitlab server itself) as the configured prometheus server and using the above query, you would see a chart like so:

[image: builtin monitoring metrics]

Of course, any tool that can view prometheus metrics will work (e.g., grafana, or your own prometheus server).

Comment: hrm, seems our gitlab has metrics disabled, how unfortunate.

Comment: @sytech any idea why I don't see "job_queue_duration_" in the official docs?
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/monitoring/prometheus/gitlab_metrics.html I'm a bit confused as to what the runner metrics would show vs gitlab metrics. It seems to me gitlab has more information in the regards to jobs itself... for example whether we are over/undercommited with concurrency & limits. Whereas runner metrics go more into details about the resources (especially cpu / memory) in the runner itself. Would you see that the same way?

Comment: I suppose this feature is only available on self managed gitlab instances, not SAAS?

Comment: @hatirlatici that's correct. gitlab.com users cannot access the instance level metrics described here.

Comment: @systech Are you sure the result is in seconds ? I tried this query, and while the shape of the graph reflects reality, the value shown seems off. I triggered multiple jobs, then checked queue time (~1min for most), but the graph shows a peak at ~17.